# VisualC 2010, project references, and include paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to use the VC2010 project references, which are the replacement for the old Project Dependencies dialog. What I am missing, however, is a way to let the referring project inherit the referred one's include and library paths. Right now, I have to manually copy any extra paths I set in the referred project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property sheets to abstract away the common compiler and linker settings.  Both of your projects then would import the same property sheet.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662426.aspx

Comment: FWIW, I'm currently doing exactly this at my workplace.  It is super convenient to separate out debug vs. release, Win32 vs. x64, MBCS vs. Unicode settings into distinct sheets.  Even better is that you make the change in once place and all your projects get the change automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this in visual studio. However since the project files are msbuild files there is nothing stopping you from using a common include in both project files.

However this is not really what you're asking is it?